# Is the current equation of both common base and common emitter transistors the same or different?

Tags: transistors

How are alpha and beta related when both are gain in different configuration respectively? Can it exist simultaneously in common base and common emitter?

Comment: Have you done any research into this question? Have you looked up the definitions of alpha and beta? Having done so what don't you still understand?

Comment: Yes beta is the current gain in common emitter configuration and alpha is current gain in common base.my doubt is how can we use alpha during derivation of common base configuration

Comment: Beta=Ic/Ib and alpha=Ic/Ie.Does this formula holds true for both configuration.my doubt is is the Ic=alpha Ie in common emitter also.when alpha is current gain of common base.

Answer (score 1):

A transistor doesn't 'know' whether it's being used in common emitter, or common base, or whatever. It just has base, emitter and collector currents, and VBE, VCE, VCB voltages.

It's our choice when we want to think about its behaviour in as simple a way as possible (ie, model it) whether we say it's common anything. What that generally means is that we think of the common terminal as 'ground', at least an AC or signal ground, and think about the voltages on the other two terminals with respect to that. That also means we can ignore the current in the common terminal, and take the ratio of the other two.

When we want to think of emitter as ground, we ignore the emitter current, and use the ratio of the remaining currents, we call Ic/Ib beta. If we want to ignore the base current, we say it's in common base, and take the ratio of Ic/Ie, and call that ratio alpha.

Given those two definitions of alpha and beta, it's trivial to relate one to the other, given that Ie = Ib+Ic.

When used as amplifiers, it's usually very clear what the easiest way to think about any transistor stage is going to be, one terminal tends to be obviously grounded. That doesn't stop us mentally treating another terminal as AC ground and doing the analysis with respect to that. It will still give the same answer, it's just that we'll have to do more mental gymnastics to write down the proper equations. In an oscillator, things aren't usually so clear, and it's an interesting exercise to take a Colpitts (or any other) oscillator, and redraw it with each transistor terminal as AC ground.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_1.html The relationship between alpha and beta is given about half way down,